# Android/Java Class Event

Tags: java, android

I usually code in VB.NET, and I am kinda new with the Android/Java environment.
So forgive my noobishness.

I have made an application with a simple New/Edit/Save/Delete button and some EditText.
In .NET I usually create my own "Mode" object which consist of 4 states which is "New/Edit/View/Idle" tied to ModeChanged Events which is then the class would be declared WithEvents so I could manage my Interface via ModeChanged Events.

Now in android I tried to make the same feature using a ModeObject Class

```
public class ModeObject {
    private enum Mode {
        IDLE, NEW, VIEW, EDIT
    }

    private Mode mode;

    public ModeObject() {
        mode = Mode.IDLE;
    }

    public void SetNew() {
        mode = Mode.NEW;
    }

    public void SetIdle() {
        mode = Mode.IDLE;
    }

    public void SetView() {
        mode = Mode.VIEW;
    }

    public void SetEdit() {
        mode = Mode.EDIT;
    }

    public String GetMode() {
        return mode.toString();
    }

    public boolean isNew() {
        if(mode==Mode.NEW)  return true;
        else return false;
    }

    public boolean isIdle() {
        if(mode==Mode.IDLE) return true;
        else return false;
    }

    public boolean isView() {
        if(mode==mode.VIEW) return true;
        else return false;
    }

    public boolean isEdit() {
        if(mode==mode.EDIT) return true;
        else return false;
    }

}
```

This is my main Activity

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.vehicle);

    private Button btnNew;
    private Button btnSave;
    private Button btnEdit;
    private Button btnCancel;
    private Button btnDelete;
    private Spinner spinner;
    private ModeObject mode = new ModeObject();

    btnNew      = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnVehicle_New);
    btnSave     = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnVehicle_Save);
    btnEdit     = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnVehicle_Edit);
    btnCancel   = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnVehicle_Cancel);
    btnDelete   = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnVehicle_Delete);

    btnNew.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mode.setNew();
        }
    });

    btnEdit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mode.setEdit();
        }
    });

    btnView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mode.setView();
        }
    });
}
```

Instead of setting the layout interface in each listener, I would like to make one listener which listen when the ModeObject value is changed and will provide me easy layout control management in one single procedure rather than multiple onClickListener.

Something like this

```
private void mode.onModeChanged() {
    if mode.isNew() {
        \\Change the interface formats
    }
    elseif mode.isIdle() {
        \\Change the interface formats
    }
    else if mode.isView() {
        \\Change the interface formats
    }
    else if mode.isEdit() {
        \\Change the interface formats
    }
}
```

How do I implement it in Android/Java? And yes I am aware with some custom Listener in which things seems vague to me as I am not accustomed to Android/Java Environment.

EDIT 1 : Sorry if my question is unclear.

EDIT 2 : ModeObject State changed from String to Enum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code from [event-dispatching-sending-messages](http://www.therealjoshua.com/2012/03/event-dispatching-sending-messages/):

### Original Source: [event-dispatching-sending-messages](http://www.therealjoshua.com/2012/03/event-dispatching-sending-messages/)

```
import java.util.Observable;

public class ModeObject extends Observable{
    public enum Mode {
        IDLE, NEW, VIEW, EDIT
    }

    private Mode mode;

    public ModeObject() {
        mode = Mode.IDLE;
    }

    public void SetNew() {
        mode = Mode.NEW;
        notifyObservers();
    }

    public void SetIdle() {
        mode = Mode.IDLE;
        notifyObservers();
    }

    public void SetView() {
        mode = Mode.VIEW;
        notifyObservers();
    }

    public void SetEdit() {
        mode = Mode.EDIT;
        notifyObservers();
    }

    public Mode GetMode() {
        return mode;
    }
}
```

Activity:

```
import java.util.Observable;
import java.util.Observer;

public class ModeChangeObserver extends Activity implements Observer{

    private ModeObject mode = new ModeObject();
    
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.vehicle);
        mode.addObserver(this);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
        switch(((ModeObject)o).GetMode())
        {
            case IDLE:
                break;
            case NEW:
                break;
            case VIEW:
                break;
            case EDIT:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Link-only answers go to a review queue and these comments and downvotes came from there. Your answer is fine now, thanks for fixing it. **Please remember to give proper attribution if you copy any material from any source, else your post will be considered as plagiarism, which is not your intention.**

Comment: @GonjiDev : Is this the one called Observer Pattern? Basically I just need to add an observer to the class and it will act as a kind of Event Handler?

Comment: Yes this is the Observer pattern. The model will act as a kind of Event Dispatcher and the Event Handler is the update method (or the Observer from your point of view).

Comment: @GonjiDev : I have tried using this kind of approach and it works well as I wanted it to be. Thanks for the help...!!

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing here has 2 grave problems. For one, you shouldn't do this with Strings (problem 1). If you *really* **have** to use a state-machine (which is an anti-pattern and thus problem 2), then at least use an enum to switch through your modes:

```
public enum Mode {
   IDLE, NEW, VIEW, EDIT
}
```

What you are doing here is a common misconception about events in general. You definitely *shouldn't* handle multiple events with the same listener. This leads to complications and "behavior switches". Such behavior switches should be ocurring at a high-level and just call a metod.

I have worked with code similar to yours, and I found it extremely unrewarding. I suggest you stay with maintaining an event listener for each button.

If you absolutely have to handle everything at once, you should be able to pass the mode to the EventListener though.

Comment: I'm just curious, but why do you think state-machine is an anti-pattern in this context? I would be interested in any link to some argumentation. (i.e. IMHO Android framework provide strong framework to support state-machine : life-cycle management, ability to save and restore state, ... maybe I'm missing something ?)

Comment: @ben75 It's important to notice that this is a quadruple state machine squeezed into a single object. And aside from violating SRP this makes code overly complicated. I'd think it's preferrable to have someone managing the states (if even) and have the states be handled by separate classes (or Activities).

Comment: Changed my ModeObject states from String to Enum. What do I do now with the Event Listener.

Comment: @AndryWijaya from what I see, you *could* pass the enum value as argument to your event listener. If I am informed correctly though, that's bad practice. Instead you should stay with each button havin g it's own listener attached. This also allows easier behavior modifications

Comment: @Vogel612 The problem is with the EventListener itself . As it is not built in, how do I make it? Can you give me some pointer/example?

Comment: @AndryWijaya I don't quite understand the problem you're having... You have 2 options in fact. (opt 1) create a double-brace initialized static inner class, or (opt 2) create a full-blown `MyEventListener extends EventListener`

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a default android application project using Eclipse
2. Create a button control on `activity_main.xml` with following code

   ```
   <Button
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button 1"
    android:onClick="onClickEvent" />
   ```
3. Add a function on `ActivityMain.java` with following code

   ```
   public void onClickEvent(View view) {
       //to do code here     
   }
   ```